# Iterating over dictionaries within dictionaries, dictionary object turning into string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
test = {'a':{'aa':'value','ab':'value'},'b':{'aa':'value','ab':'value'}}

#test 1
for x in test:
    print(x['aa'])

#test 2
for x in test:
    print(test[x]['aa'])
```

Why does test 1 give me a `TypeError: string indices must be integers` but test 2 pass?

Does the for loop turn the dictionary into a string?

Comment: No, you iterate over the keys, you want to iterate over the values.

Comment: Just from looking at it, I would expect it to be the other way round. Are you sure what you have written is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you iterate over a dictionary, you **iterate over the keys**. So that means in the **first loop, `x = 'a'`**, and in the second `x = 'b'` (or vice versa, since dictionaries are *unordered*). It thus simply "*ignores*" the values. It makes no sense to index a string with a string (well there is no straightforward interpretation for `'a'['aa']`, or at least not really one I can come up with that would be "logical" for a signifcant number of programmers).

Although this may look quite strange, it is quite consistent with the fact that a *membership check* for example also works on the keys (if we write `'a' in some_dict`, it does *not* look to the values either).

If you want to use the *values*, you need to iterate over `.values()`, so:

```
for x in test.values():
    print(x['aa'])
```

If you however use your second thest, then this works, since then `x` is a key (for example `'a'`), and hence `test[x]` will fetch you the corresponding value. If you then process `test[x]` further, you thus process the values of the dictionary.

You can iterate concurrently over keys and values with **`.items()`**:

```
for k, x in test.items():
    # ...
    pass
```

Here in the first iteration `k` will be `'a'` and `x` will be `{'aa':'value','ab':'value'}`, in the second iteration `k` will be `'b'` and `x` will be `{'aa':'value','ab':'value'}` (again the iterations can be swapped, since dictionaries are unordered).

If you thus are interested in the outer key, and the value that is associated with the `'aa'` key of the corresponding subdictionary, you can use:

```
for k, x in test.items():
    v = x['aa']
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: Also, the fact that test 2 works (i.e., that `test[x]` makes sense) depends on the fact that you're iterating over the keys.

Comment: How would I get the outer key and the inner value such that the output is 

a, value

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over a dictionary with a `for`, you're not iterating over the items, but over the keys (`'a', 'b'`). These are just strings that mean nothing. That's why you have to do it as on test 2. You could also iterate over the items with `test.items()`.